# C#: How to execute them, with the requirements on Console?

Tags: python, c#, .net, compiler-errors, compilation

I needed to write C# code inside the file and run them.
But the problem while running is the file name should be MAIN or the class inside should be equivalent to the file name.
Can't do both, but need to run them for practicing.

Is there no way just like in python we run using the command `python fileName.py` and it runs the program, so can't we do something similar here, it says to build project too, but can't build for every single 1kb file.

The file names are below, they are problems which I should practice on and run them.

```
[nitkarshc@nitkarshC C#]$ ls
Easy  Expert  Hard  Medium  README.md  veryEasy  veryHard
[nitkarshc@nitkarshC C#]$ cd veryEasy/
[nitkarshc@nitkarshC veryEasy]$ ls -1v
Main.cs
tempCodeRunnerFile.cs
'[1] Return the Sum of Two Numbers [VE].cs'
'[2] Convert Minutes into Seconds [VE].cs'
'[3] Return the Next Number from the Integer Passed [VE].cs'
'[4] Circuit Power Calculator [VE].cs'
'[5] Convert Age to Days [VE].cs'
'[6] Area of a Triangle [VE].cs'
'[7] Return the Remainder from Two Numbers [VE].cs'
'[8] Is the Number Less than or Equal to Zero_ [VE].cs'
'[9] Less Than 100_ [VE].cs'
'[10] Are the Numbers Equal_ [VE].cs'
'[11] Return Something to Me! [VE].cs'
'[12] Flip the Boolean [VE].cs'
'[13] Convert Hours into Seconds [VE].cs'
'[14] Sum of Polygon Angles [VE].cs'
'[15] Are the Numbers Equal_ [VE].cs'
'[16] Basic Variable Assignment [VE].cs'
'[17] Using the _&&_ Operator [VE].cs'
'[18] Basketball Points [VE].cs'
'[19] Find the Perimeter of a Rectangle [VE].cs'
'[20] Name Greeting! [VE].cs'
'[21] The Farm Problem [VE].cs'
'[22] Football Points [VE].cs'
'[23] Return the First Element in an Array [VE].cs'
'[24] Buggy Code (Part 4) [VE].cs'
'[25] Convert Hours and Minutes into Seconds [VE].cs'
'[26] Maximum Edge of a Triangle [VE].cs'
'[27] Inches to Feet [VE].cs'
'[28] Flip the Integer Boolean [VE].cs'
'[29] Check if an Integer is Divisible By Five [VE].cs'
'[30] Correct the Mistakes [VE].cs'
[nitkarshc@nitkarshC veryEasy]$
```

I tried running them.
But error is like, something Main class can't be run with different file name or vice - versa.
I have multiple files on the same folder, even if I build a project and somehow run them. It says only one entry can only be there, with regards to main.
How can I execute like python?

Comment: Python is a scripting language and can be run "on the fly" whereas C# needs to be compiled to be run, @imhadas explained it in more detail, but the difference is similar to that between javascript and java.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're having is that C# behaves a lot differently than python. You don't have an option to compile and run singular .cs files. You need to create a project first.

If you're using the .NET CLI tool it's just this command: `dotnet new console -n "My application"`. This will create a new console application. From that you can just implement in the generated .cs file your program, or just create new classes in the project directory and you can reference those classes in the program and run them from there.

To build and run the app you can use the `dotnet run` command which will automatically build and run your program.

Comment: Maybe take note of the fact that in recent versions of dotnet, no explicit main-function will be created in the apps Program.cs (..what your error complains about). The apps main-function is automagically created from the Program.cs so don't worry about it

Comment: What is .NET and C#, why they go together?
Isn't framework supposed to be used as framework?
Like Django in python or flask or similar?
Can you give me a a link to some post or tutorial like how to run .cs file (multiple file if it is the case) on windows pc using IDE.